This method only supports 0x-prefixed hex strings
I signed message with domain, types and value using wagmi module through MetaMask.
The code is as follows:
import { useChainId } from "wagmi";

import React from 'react';
import { usePublicClient, useWalletClient } from 'wagmi';

import { FallbackProvider, JsonRpcProvider, BrowserProvider, JsonRpcSigner } from 'ethers';

function publicClientToProvider(publicClient) {\
    const { chain, transport } = publicClient;
    const network = {
        chainId: chain.id,
        name: chain.name,
        ensAddress: chain.contracts?.ensRegistry?.address,
    };
    if (transport.type === 'fallback') {
        const providers = transport.transports.map(({ value }) => new JsonRpcProvider(value?.url, network));
        if (providers.length === 1)
            return providers[0];
        return new FallbackProvider(providers);
    }
    return new JsonRpcProvider(transport.url, network);
}

function walletClientToSigner(walletClient) {
    const { account, chain, transport } = walletClient;
    const network = {
        chainId: chain.id,
        name: chain.name,
        ensAddress: chain.contracts?.ensRegistry?.address,
    };
    const provider = new BrowserProvider(transport, network);
    const signer = new JsonRpcSigner(provider, account.address);
    return signer;
}

function useEthersSigner({ chainId }) {
    const { data: walletClient } = useWalletClient({ chainId });
    return React.useMemo(() => (walletClient ? walletClientToSigner(walletClient) : undefined), [walletClient]);
}

const chainId = useChainId();
const signer = useEthersSigner(chainId);
...
const signature = await signer.signTypedData({
                    name: "Trading Token",
                    version: "1",
                    chainId: chainId,
                    verifyingContract: token,
                }, {
                    Permit: [
                        { name: "content", type: "string" },
                        { name: "nonce", type: "uint256" },
                    ],
                }, {
                    content: "Enable Trading",
                    nonce: 0,
                });
...

When calling signer.signTypedData() function, MetaMask has an error.
The error is as follows:
Message: This method only supports 0x-prefixed hex strings but input was:

Code: Error

Stack:
Error: This method only supports 0x-prefixed hex strings but input was: 
  at r.assertIsHexString (chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/common-4.js:27:21821)
  at r.toChecksumAddress (chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/common-4.js:27:9005)
  at chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/ui-3.js:1:125557
  at LavaPack.loadBundle.n.default (chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/ui-3.js:1:125571)
  at ba (chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/common-7.js:1:60103)
  at As (chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/common-7.js:1:104934)
  at Iu (chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/common-7.js:1:90842)
  at Cu (chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/common-7.js:1:90767)
  at Tu (chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/common-7.js:1:88115)
  at chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/common-7.js:1:46513
  at r.unstable_runWithPriority (chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/common-7.js:1:122601)
  at Qi (chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/common-7.js:1:46222)
  at eo (chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/common-7.js:1:46458)
  at Zi (chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/common-7.js:1:46393)
  at Bu (chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/common-7.js:1:103141)
  at r.unstable_runWithPriority (chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/common-7.js:1:122601)
  at Qi (chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/common-7.js:1:46222)
  at Fu (chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/common-7.js:1:102792)
  at chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/common-7.js:1:102703
  at F (chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/common-7.js:1:121983)
  at T.port1.onmessage (chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/common-7.js:1:120727)

How can I fix this?

The error you encountered may be due to the fact that useChainId() returns the chainId as a number, while the EIP-712 typed data specification requires the chainId to be passed as a hex string. You can resolve this issue by converting the chainId to a hex string (using ethers.toBeHex()) when passing it to the signTypedData function.
So, the revised signTypedData function call would be:
...
const signature = await signer.signTypedData({
                    name: "Trading Token",
                    version: "1",
                    chainId: ethers.toBeHex(chainId),
                    verifyingContract: token,
                }, {
                    Permit: [
                        { name: "content", type: "string" },
                        { name: "nonce", type: "uint256" },
                    ],
                }, {
                    content: "Enable Trading",
                    nonce: 0,
                });
...

